# Swift: custom key-value encoding with Encodable conformance in struct

Tags: json, swift, encodable

```swift
struct Struct: Encodable {
  let key: String
  let value: String
}

let aStruct = Struct(key: "abc", value: "xyz")
```

Given this struct and the default `Encodable` conformance provided, JSON encoding produces

```
{
    key = abc;
    value = xyz;
}
```

whereas instead I'd like to to encode it to

```
{
    abc = xyz;
}
```

how do I conform this struct to `Encodable` to end up with this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `encode(to encoder: Encoder)` and encode the struct as single dictionary

```
struct Struct: Encodable {
    let key: String
    let value: String
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode([key:value])
    }
}
```